# SQL when to user object types

Tags: sql, oracle

When should I create regular tables for my domain (creating regular tables), and when should I create object types (creating types, and tables of those types)  when creating a database in Oracle?

Which advantages and disadvantages have these ways of creating databases? When should I create the database one way, and when the other way?

Comment: A Type is more like a temp table - use when you have data that you do not need persisted.  A Table is more for permanent data that you put indexes on and query from .

Comment: This is just my opinion, based on what I normally do; there's nothing wrong if someone / everyone disagrees. Anyway: there are two "when" questions in your first sentence, and my answers are: *always* and *never*, respectively. I take Oracle to be the *relational* DBMS. *Object* is a nice add-on for those who need that. I don't (lucky me) & think that it's just not worth the effort.

Comment: Well, you will generally need tables in a database, so I'm not sure what you mean by the first question. Object types are brilliant as programming constructs in PL/SQL, less useful as table templates ('table of type'), so I guess I'd say 1 always, 2 as needed for PL/SQL code, 3 never. One problem with object tables is Oracle chose not to expose them in the `user|all|dba_tables` views, so they won't work with most third party tools that look for tables. Then there is the added complication and constraints of type evolution etc, all for very little benefit.